# How to move files leaving symlinks behind?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

How can I move/copy files from one directory to another, leaving the symlinks in the **original directory**. I know the `ln -s`creates symlinks in the destination, but I want to leave the symlinks in the source directory and move the actual files to a new one. How can I do this?

Comment: The best answer to this question is here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228166/7000

Answer (score 4):

Process the files individually, e.g.,

```
cd $original_directory  
for i in <files to process> ; do  
    mv ./$i $new_directory/  
    ln -s $new_directory/$i ./$i
done
```

or, if copying, replace the `mv` command line with

```
    cp ./$i $new_directory/  
    rm ./$i
```

Comment: The cp/rm version - what are the possible benefits of it? Looks like it does the same only much slower :)

Comment: @Sergey One could check the exit status of `cp` and proceed to remove only if it was successful.

Comment: @lgarzo: That would be valuable if `mv` wasn't checking if copy succeeded before deleting the file - but that would be a serious bug in `mv` :)

Comment: Are "$new_directory" and "<files to process>" "special variables", where the last argument I give the script will always be considered "$new_directory" and whatever initial arguments are considered "<files to process>"?. Does this apply to any other script I write?

Or are you implying that I should fill in the blanks, like using "$1" and "$2"? 

Sorry for the question but I'm very new to coding in general.

Comment: Replace `$original_directory` and `$new_directory` with the directories you want to move from/to, or set them like this `original_directory=/home/walt/from`. For use in scripts, you have to parse the arguments yourself. See the **getopts builtin** in `man bash`.